# Separate columns based on first and last comma in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file shown below which I have to read through pandas.

```
1, Apple, 1
2, Apple, Banana, 2
3, Strawberry, 3
```

Multiple commas appear in my second line. I need to separate them so that the data before the first comma goes in the first column, the data after the last comma goes in the last column, and everything else in between goes in the second column, as can be seen below.

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1 |
| 2 | Apple, Banana | 2 |
| 3 | Strawberry | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file, then perform the split, finally create the dataframe.

To split the data, you can first split from left on `,`  with `maxsplit=1`, then split the last item from right again with `maxsplit=1`.

```py
f = open('file.csv')
lines = []
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip().split(', ', maxsplit=1)  # split from left
    line.extend(line.pop(-1).rsplit(', ', maxsplit=1))  #split last item from right
    lines.append(line)
f.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=[f'Column{i}' for i in range(1, len(lines[0])+1)])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  Column1        Column2 Column3
0       1          Apple       1
1       2  Apple, Banana       2
2       3     Strawberry       3
```

**PS:** It is always a good idea to split the string with `maxsplit` parameter *if obvious*, because it avoids unnecessary `splits` and `joins`

Comment: `with open('file.csv') was f:` is better and doesn't require `f.close()`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, yeah that is so True, and I also personally prefer context manager, but I used `StringIO` to test above code, that is why I just added `open` and `close`

Comment: `with open('file.csv') as f: lines = [[row[0]] + [','.join(row[1:-1])] + [row[-1]] for l in f if (row := l.strip().split(',')) is not None] ` as one list comprehension.

Comment: The assignment operator you are using `:=` is going to work on Python 3.8+ only.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the entire line at commas and concatenate as needed:

```
data = list()
with open("test.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = line.strip().split(", ")
        data.append({"Column1": words[0],
                     "Column2": ", ".join(words[1:-1]), 
                     "Column3": words[-1]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
  Column1        Column2 Column3
0       1          Apple       1
1       2  Apple, Banana       2
2       3     Strawberry       3
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the same basic answer that others have already presented. Split the text into words, assign the first and last to their own list, and save the rest to a middle list. Then, create the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

input = open("comma_pandas.txt", 'r')
column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = []

for line in input:
    tokens = [token.strip() for token in line.split(',')]
    column1.append(tokens.pop(0))
    column3.append(tokens.pop())
    column2.append(tokens)

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': column1, "column2": column2, "column3": column3})

print(df)
```

Produces

```
  column1          column2 column3
0       1          [Apple]       1
1       2  [Apple, Banana]       2
2       3     [Strawberry]       3
```

If you want column 2 to hold a string instead of a list of strings, you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd

input = open("comma_pandas.txt", 'r')
column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = []

for line in input:
    tokens = [token.strip() for token in line.split(',')]
    column1.append(tokens.pop(0))
    column3.append(tokens.pop())
    column2.append(", ".join(tokens))

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': column1, "column2": column2, "column3": column3})

print(df)
```

which produces

```
  column1        column2 column3
0       1          Apple       1
1       2  Apple, Banana       2
2       3     Strawberry       3
```

Comment: How to remove '[' and ']' characters from the beginning and ending of column2 ?

Comment: If you wish for column2 to hold a string instead of a list of strings, I will add a variant.